# Prove $(A^T)^{-1}$ = $(A^{-1})^T$ whenever $A$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices

Prove $(A^T)^{-1}$ = $(A^{-1})^T$ for any invertible matrix $A.$

I actually don't know where to start. I do not think I can just apply index laws.

Any help is cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Try taking the transpose of the equation
$$AA^{-1}=I.$$

Comment: using that, I got $(A^{-1})^T A^T = I$ and $A^T (A^{-1})^T = I$, then $(A^{-1})^T A^T = A^T (A^{-1})^T$, but what next? Sorry if I've been asking too much - been stoning at this for a while

Comment: @Clinton Which means that $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$, by the definition of inverses. $(A^T)^{-1}$ is *defined* to be the matrix $B$ such that $BA^T=A^TB=I$.

Comment: @AlexBecker ah. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As we know $AA^{-1}=I$.
Now taking transpose both sides, we get
                   $$(AA^{-1})^T = I^T$$ which implies
               $$[ (A^{-1})^T ](A^T) = I$$
Now multiply both sides with $[(A^T)^{-1}]$ at right side,
      $$[(A^{-1})^T]{(A^T)(A^T)^{-1}} = (A^T)^{-1}$$
Here  $(A^T)(A^T)^{-1}$  will form identity $I$,
Since we know $AA^{-1} = I$,
Therefore     $$(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$$
Hence Proved!

Answer (score 5):

first we define a "B" matrix like below :
$$B = (A^{-1})$$
so :
$$B^T=(A^{-1})^T    *$$
and we can write :
$$AB = I$$ 
then 
$$(AB)^T=I^T \textrm{ and } 
B^T A^T =I$$
From this equation we can say that : 
$$B^T=(A^T)^{-1}$$ 
and finally from * we can write :
$$B^T=(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$$

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$A^{-1}=\frac{\text{adj} (A)}{|A|}$$
Transpose:
$$\begin{align}(A^{-1})^T&=\left(\frac{\text{adj}(A)}{|A|}\right)^T=\\
&=\frac{(\text{adj} (A))^T}{|A|}=\\
&=\frac{\text{adj} (A^T)}{|A|}=\\
&=\frac{\text{adj} (A^T)}{|A^T|}=\\
&=(A^T)^{-1}.\end{align}$$
The following properties of [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) and [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) were used:
$$\begin{align}(\text{adj} (A))^T&=\text{adj} (A^T);\\
(cA)^T&=c(A)^T;\\
|A|&=|A^T|.\end{align}$$

Answer (score -3):

$A^T(A^T)^{-1} = I$   ;                        $ eq^n 1$

taking   transpose  on  both   side of $ eq^n 1 $

$[(A^T)^{-1}]^T A = I $;    $eq^n 1.1$

[Since $(AB)^T= B^TA^T $ & $I^T=I$ , $(A^T)^T=A$]

Now  to hold above $eq^n 1.1$ it must satisfy the relation below

$[(A^T)^{-1}]^T  =  A^{-1} $   ;           $eq^n 2 $

taking transpose on $eq^n 2 , $ we get
$ (A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T $